# Get today's files via search with plone.restapi plugin return error query plone

Tags: datetime, request, postman, plone

I am making a GET request using plone.restapi with postman that should return the last day files using the plone @search. The problem is that when it sends the request I have an error on the query that requires the data and I return the following JSON where the errors are represented. I also tried to write the date in all the different formats possible using the Timezone, but the result is always the same. Does anyone know how to do?

This is my URL: `http://192.168.197.28:8080/docrai-cms/@search?advanced_search=False&sort_on=&sort_order=&SearchableText=pdf&advanced_search=True&portal_type%3Alist=File&created.query%3Arecord%3Alist%3Adate=2019%2F05%2F01&created.range%3Arecord=min`

This is the working browser URL: `http://192.168.197.28:8080/docrai-cms/@@search?advanced_search=False&sort_on=&sort_order=&SearchableText=pdf&advanced_search=True&portal_type%3Alist=File&created.query%3Arecord%3Alist%3Adate=2019%2F05%2F01&created.range%3Arecord=min`

These are the attached photos:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide error-messages in a textual format. That way search-engines can index them and peeps can copy&paste stuff easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi/blob/master/docs/source/serialization.rst#dates-and-times):

> datetime types will be serialized to an ISO 8601 datestring

It should be `2019-05-01`, no slashes `/` like you are using in the URI-encoded form `%2F`.

This works using `curl` for the request:

```
curl -i "localhost:8080/Plone/@search?created.query=2019-05-09&created.range=min" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

That returns all items which were created on the given day or after.

For requesting a date-range one can do (showing only query for brevity):

```
?created.query=2019-05-09T08:00:00&created.query=2019-05-09T20:00:00&created.range=min:max
```

That returns all items which were created on the given day between 8 a.m. and 8 p.m.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I followed also the docs but the problem it always the same.

Comment: Check to *not* use slashes, but minus-character for dividing year/month/day.